# What is the product of two sets of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume we have a matrix $B$ of eigenvectors which is p*p, where the eigenvectors are arranged according to their corresponding eigenvalues (i.e. first column contains the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue).

If we then subdivide the matrix into two sub-matrices

$B_r$ which is p*r containing the first r columns of $B$ and another matrix $B_{p-r}$ which is p*p-r containing the remaining p-r columns of $B$ (all the columns are still in their original order)

Then I think that the matrix product $B_r'*B_{p-r}$ where ' indicates transpose should be the zero matrix of size p*p-r.

1.) Is this correct?
2.) If so how can I prove this result?
3.) How does this fit in with the result that the product of two orthogonal matrices should also be orthogonal?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that $B$ is a matrix of eigenvectors?

Comment: I simply mean that each column of $B$ corresponds to one eigenvector of the eigenvector set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is generally true only for normal matrices (e.g., orthogonal, symmetric/Hermitian). Normal matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors, so, assuming a normal matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times p}$ has an eigendecomposition $A=UDU^{*}$ and if $U=[U_1,U_2]$, where $U_1\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times r}$ and $U_2\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times(p-r)}$, then $U_1^*U_2=0$ as well as $U_2^*U_1=0$. This follows simply from the fact that $U$ is unitary and hence has orthogonal columns.

This is not true for general matrices. However, if the matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times p}$ is diagonalisable, then there is a nonsingular $X$ and diagonal $D$ such that $A=XDX^{-1}$. If we denote $Y^*=X^{-1}$ and $X=[X_1,X_2]$, $Y=[Y_1,Y_2]$, with $\cdot_1\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times r}$ and $\cdot_2\in\mathbb{C}^{p\times(p-r)}$ (for $\cdot=X$ and $\cdot=Y$), we have $Y_1^*X_2=0$ and $Y_2^*X_1=0$, which follows simply from the fact that $Y^*$ is the inverse of $X$.